# Spring Boot ShedLock "relation "shedlock" does not exist"

Tags: spring-data-jpa, shedlock

I added ShedLock to my project to prevent working of scheduled job more than one time. I configured it like below but I'm getting

"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "shedlock" does not exist" error.

This is lockProviderBean:

```
@Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(
                JdbcTemplateLockProvider.Configuration.builder()
                        .withJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource))
                        .usingDbTime() 
                        .build()
        );
    }
```

This is scheduled job:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cronProperty:0 00 23 * * *}")
@SchedulerLock(name = "schedulerLockName")
public void scheduledJob() {
       ..............
}
```

I added these notations to my class which contains schduledJob method:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Component
@Configuration
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "2m")
```

I'm using Spring Data to do database operations and using these properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://ip:port/databaseName?currentSchema=schemeName
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database = postgresql
spring.datasource.platform = postgresql
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = password
```

Comment: Create shedlock table manually. Details https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#jdbctemplate

Answer (score 4):

maybe this is what you are missing:

> If you need to specify a schema, you can set it in the table name
> using the usual dot notation new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(datasource,
> "my_schema.shedlock")

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the table as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#jdbctemplate).

Comment: I have the exact same problem when I perform a clean with Flyway, which deletes everything from database. When I restart all my containers/volumes and also the API, it fails to works and keeps telling me the relation does not exist. How is that even possible ? There must be some state left somewhere. I'm using the dependency with gradle that adds it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem too even though shedlock table has been created.

Workarounds for this is by

1. Setting pg's user default schema using `ALTER ROLE YourPgUser SET search_path TO ...` , or
2. Specifing shedlock schema on LockProvider bean

```
    @Bean
    public LockProvider getLockProvider(@Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("SET search_path TO domaindbschema");
        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(jdbcTemplate);
    }
```

or another style

```
    @Bean
    public LockProvider getLockProvider(@Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(jdbcTemplate, "domaindbschema.shedlock");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If This is in the server, you need to modify the privileges to the table. contact to BD team

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling with below error with shedlock scheduler implementation database entry

**org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO shedlock(name, lock_until, locked_at, locked_by) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

Fix is just in created bean with LockProvider provide you schema name with table name

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
 
    @Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource, "YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME.SHEDLOCK");
    }
}
```